# Codeigniter has already double quote , and single quote already how to echo base_url

Tags: php, html, codeigniter

I'm doing a shopping cart and I want to make a logo button that when user clicks on the logo button it will delete an order.(it will anchor to method remove in controller)

I want to assign variable like this

```
<?php 
$path = "<img src='echo base_url("images/cart_cross.jpg");' width='25px' height='20px'>";        
echo anchor('shopping/remove/' . $item['rowid'], $path); 
?>
```

**but the $path is not working** for me because it has already double quote , and single quote already

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try this

```
$path = '<img src="'. base_url("images/cart_cross.jpg").'" width="25px" height="20px">'; 

echo anchor('shopping/remove/' . $item['rowid'], $path);
```